# Highcharts is not a function

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I can't get highcharts to work, i get error highcharts is not a function. I have a lot of scripts an i looked at network tab and highcharts are loaded after jquery. Jquery version is 1.10.2 which should work with highcharts.

```
<link href='https://apollo.telekomcg.com/fonts/fonts.css' rel='stylesheet' 
type='text/css'/>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-combobox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-filestyle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/EArchiveNew.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/JavaScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/colResizable-1.5.min.js"></script>
```

There are all my scripts. Function for graphing is in JavaScript1.js. And here is the function:

```
function myjava() {
$('#MainContent_myDiv').highcharts({

    chart: {
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});


Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
    text: 'Add Issue ',
    onclick: function () {
        alert('OK');
    }
});
```

}

myjava is onclick function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work correctly in the online editor: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nx0e4wa5/

Although your error doesn't indicate this, I would recommend checking the following possibilities:
-you are using `contextButton`, but there is no export module in your code:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

-jQuery might be loaded incorrectly, check it with a random CDN:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js"></script>
```

-perhaps you made a typo or lost the div, that you reference in your chart

```
<div id="MainContent_myDi"></div>
```